# Bootstrap - Custom Form

Tags: php, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap. I am trying to create a working form, but the submit function doesn't work.
Here is my form HTML:

```
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="mph.php" method="POST">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                            <fieldset>

                            <!-- Form Name -->
                            <legend>Map Problem Reporter</legend>

                            <!-- Select Basic -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="selectbasic">What map?</label>
                              <div class="col-md-6">
                                <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control">
                                  <option value="1">6 Stages of Parkour</option>
                                  <option value="2">20 Stages of Parkour</option>
                                </select>
                              </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Multiple Radios -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="radios">What kind of problem?</label>
                              <div class="col-md-4">
                              <div class="radio">
                                <label for="radios-0">
                                  <input type="radio" name="radios" id="radios-0" value="1">
                                  Blocks
                                </label>
                                </div>
                              <div class="radio">
                                <label for="radios-1">
                                  <input type="radio" name="radios" id="radios-1" value="2">
                                  Commands / Command Blocks
                                </label>
                                </div>
                              <div class="radio">
                                <label for="radios-2">
                                  <input type="radio" name="radios" id="radios-2" value="">
                                  Entities / Items
                                </label>
                                </div>
                              <div class="radio">
                                <label for="radios-3">
                                  <input type="radio" name="radios" id="radios-3" value="">
                                  Other (describe in the next text field)
                                </label>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Textarea -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textarea">Describe the Problem</label>
                              <div class="col-md-4">                     
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="textarea" name="textarea"></textarea>
                              </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Select Basic -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="selectbasic">What is the priority?</label>
                              <div class="col-md-6">
                                <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control">
                                  <option value="1">Huge! It breaks the map!</option>
                                  <option value="2">Big</option>
                                  <option value="">Noticeable</option>
                                  <option value="">Barely Noticeable</option>
                                  <option value="">Almost Hidden</option>
                                  <option value="">I do not know</option>
                                </select>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data">
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
```

And here is my current PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2'])) {
$data = $_POST['field1'] . '-' . $_POST['field2'] . "\n";
$ret = file_put_contents('mpr.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
if($ret === false) {
    die('There was an error writing this file');
}
else {
    echo "$ret bytes written to file";
}
}
else {
   die('no post data to process');
}
?>
```

When I click "Save Data" in the form, it doesn't update my mpr.txt with the information. Please help.

Comment: 1. Which submit function? 2.Where is your "Save Data" in your form? Also add the att. method to your form tags like: `<form method="post">`

Comment: The answer is quit obvious! PHP is trying to find `field1` and `field2` posted. But in your HTML form you did not define these two properties, consequently PHP won't update the file!

Comment: People have given their time to help you. Please don't punish them and prevent future visitors from learning by deleting or vandalising this.

Comment: @Flexo I am not "punishing" future people by not allowing them to see this. I am going to remake the thread (once it is deleted), and change a few things.

Comment: You're welcome to improve your questions, but deleting this now just wastes the time of the people who've tried to help you.

Comment: @Flexo No, the whole point of me deleting and recreating the thread is to delete the answers and comments (to start "with a clean slate" if you will).

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 problems:

1) You have created `2 forms` with

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
```

and

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
```

which should be `1`

and

2) You are missing the `action` attribute in `<form>` tag i.e. it should be `<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="<php file name>" method="<request type>">`

correct these and I think you should be through.

You do not see the data in your `.txt file` because you do not have any field named `field1` and `field2` in your html page. The field names have to match in both html and php files to write/read the data correctly.  Please correct the names and you should be through.

Also would appreciate if you accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quit obvious! PHP is trying to find field1 and field2 posted. But in your HTML form you did not define these two properties, consequently PHP won't update the file!

**EDIT:**

If you submit the form and `print_r($_POST)` you will get the follow array:

```
Array ( [selectbasic] => 1 [textarea] => [submit] => Save Data )
```

As you see, there is no `[field1]` or `[field2]` in the response!

Which means PHP cannot proceed to to open and update the text file!

To prevent this, you should define `field1` and `field2` in your HTML form by adding these input tags or updating the existing ones.

For instance, if you are interested in the `select` tag and the `textarea` tag, you should whether update you HTML code or you php code.

You could go with PHP code by updating your if statement into `if(isset($_POST['selectbasic'], $_POST['textarea']))` or in your HTML form change the `name="selectbasic"` into `name="field1"` and `name="textarea"` into `name="field2` and keep your current php code and so your current PHP if statement that says: `if(isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2']))`

I hope this explains it all!

Comment: No that's not it! when you submit the form, PHP looks for `$_POST['field1']` and `$_POST['field2']` in the response! In your code you did not define `name="field1"` and `name="field2"`

Comment: Did you change this line too: `$data = $_POST['field1'] . '-' . $_POST['field2'] . "\n";` into `$data = $_POST['selectbasic'] . '-' . $_POST['textarea'] . "\n";` ?

Comment: Just update these lines and with the following code and it will work:
`if(isset($_POST['selectbasic']) && isset($_POST['textarea'])) {
$data = $_POST['selectbasic'] . '-' . $_POST['textarea'] . "\n";
$ret = file_put_contents('mpr.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);`
I have already tested it and it worked on my server.
PS: make sure the `mpr.txt` is in the same directory as the `mph.php` file.

Comment: You can email me here: karimwaiyl@gmail.com

Comment: Please if you find my answer helpful, do not forget to mark it as a solution to your question. It works for me, I have tested it on my server.